# Droid Explorer Cannot Start because Unable to locate aapt.exe in the SDK path

Tags: android-sdk

Iam just installed Droid Explorer version 0.9.04 (x64) This morning and already locate the SDK folder but when i luch the application it's show me that Droid Explorer can't locate aapt.exe in the SDK path. Anyone can help me?